# Error found when installing scala in ubuntu

Tags: scala

I am installing scala in ubuntu 15.10. 
When I use the command: `apt-get install scala`, it shows this output:

```
Err http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe scala-library all     2.11.6-1
  404  Not Found [IP : 91.189.88.161 80]
Err http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ wily/universe scala all 2.11.6-1
  404  Not Found [IP : 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Impossible de récupérer http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu    /pool/universe/s/scala/scala-library_2.11.6-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP :     91.189.88.161 80]

E: Impossible de récupérer http://tn.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu    /pool/universe/s/scala/scala_2.11.6-1_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP :     91.189.88.161 80]

E: Impossible de récupérer certaines archives, peut-être devrez-vous lancer apt-get update ou essayer avec --fix-missing ?
```

How can I resolve it ? Any help please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download archive, unzip it

```
wget https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.12.3/scala-2.12.3.tgz
sudo cp scala-2.12.3.tgz /usr/local/share/scala-2.12.3.tgz
cd /usr/local/share
sudo tar xzvf scala-2.12.3.tgz
sudo rm scala-2.12.3.tgz
```

and update `PATH`

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

adding lines

```
export SCALA_HOME=/usr/local/share/scala-2.12.3
export PATH=$PATH:$SCALA_HOME/bin
```

Now Scala should work

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_144).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> 1+1
res0: Int = 2
```

You can read the page https://www.scala-lang.org/download/